# Em que local deve ficar um método globalmente utilizada?

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho um método chamado parser, em resumo seu código é:

```
public function parser($local) {

    $file = storage_path($local);
    $csv = Reader::createFromPath($file);
    // remove cabeçalho (ignora a primeira linha
    // $novo = $reader->setOffset(0)->fetchAll();
    // retorna o cabeçalho
    // $headers = $csv->fetchOne();

    foreach ($csv as $row) {
        $novo[] = ["nome" => $row[0], "idade" => $row[1], "outro" => $row[2]];
    }

    \DB::table('teste')->insert($novo);
}
```

O método acima será utilizado em diversos controllers diferentes, logo minhas dúvidas são:

- Por se tratar de um método que poderá está presentes em muitos controllers, aonde devo colocar este código?
- Em que parte da estrutura do Laravel devo alocar o arquivo que terá este código?
- Algum exemplo ou demonstração prática?

Answer (score 2):

> Em que parte da estrutura do Laravel devo alocar o arquivo que terá este código?

Você pode criar seu próprio arquivo para carregar as suas próprias funções.

Crie um arquivo `resources/funcoes.php`

Altere seu `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    // ...
    "files": [
        "resources/helpers.php"
    ]
}
```

Rode o comando `composer dump`.

Agora todas as funções que você adicionar em `resources/funcoes.php` estarão disponíveis globalmente.

Answer (score -2):

Também é possível colocar esse método num controlador à sua escolha e nos controladores em que quiser utilizar o método poderá fazê-lo da seguinte forma:

```
app('App\Http\Controllers\NomeController')->parser();
```